# When radio button checked div hide/show text field works but does not insert in database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I write code using jQuery for radio button. I hide/show textbox when radio button checked, it works but it does not inserty the value in database for Artwork.

[image: my radio button]

```
  $Order_date = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['Order_date']);
  $Confirm_Design_Date = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['Confirm_Design_Date']);
  $Due_Date = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['Due_Date']);
  $Name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['Name']);
  $Type_of_Customer = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['Type_of_Customer']);
  $phone = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['phone']);
  $Email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['Email']);
  $pic = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['pic']);
  $design = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['design']);
  $Output = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['Output']);
  $Finishing = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['Finishing']);
  $Submit_date = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['Submit_date']);
  $Product = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['Product']);
  $Size = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['Size']);
  $Material_implode = implode(" , ",$_POST['Material']);
  $Material = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$Material_implode);
  $Type_finishing = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['Type_finishing']);
  $Kuantiti = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['Kuantiti']);
  $Artwork = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['Artwork']);
  $Pengantin_P = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['Pengantin_P']);
  $Pengantin_L = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['Pengantin_L']);
  $Jum_Hantaran = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['Jum_Hantaran']);
  $Bank_pilihan = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['Bank_pilihan']);
  $Nama_singkatan = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['Nama_singkatan']);
  $Tarikh_akad_nikah = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['Tarikh_akad_nikah']);
  $total = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['total']);
  $Deposit = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['Deposit']);
  $Balance = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['Balance']);
  $Receipt_no = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['Receipt_no']);


  $sql = "INSERT INTO mockup_check (Order_date, Confirm_Design_Date, Due_Date, Name, Type_of_Customer, phone, Email, pic, design, Output, Finishing, Submit_date, Product, Size, Material, Type_finishing,
  Kuantiti, Artwork, Pengantin_P, Pengantin_L, Jum_Hantaran, Bank_pilihan, Nama_singkatan, Tarikh_akad_nikah,  total, Deposit, Balance, Receipt_no)
  VALUES
  ('$Order_date','$Confirm_Design_Date','$Due_Date','$Name','$Type_of_Customer','$phone','$Email','$pic','$design','$Output','$Finishing','$Submit_date','$Product','$Size','$Material','$Type_finishing','$Kuantiti','$Artwork','$Pengantin_P','$Pengantin_L','$Jum_Hantaran','$Bank_pilihan','$Nama_singkatan','$Tarikh_akad_nikah','$total','$Deposit','$Balance','$Receipt_no')";

  $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
}
```

html code and php script. form success isset but database for Artwork
not inserted

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  $("input[name='Artwork']").click(function(){
    var value = $('input[name=Artwork]:checked').val();
    if(value === 'Other'){
      $('#div_ifOther').show();
    }
    else if(value !== 'Other'){
      $('#div_ifOther').hide();
    }
  });
});
</script>


<div id="div_id_select" class="form-group required">
  <label for="id_Artwork"  class="control-label col-md-4  requiredField"> Artwork :<span class="asteriskField">*</span> </label>
  <div class="controls col-md-9 "  style="margin-bottom: 10px">
    <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" checked="checked" name="Artwork" id="ifUsb"  value="Usb"  style="margin-bottom: 10px">Usb</label>
    <label class="radio-inline"> <input type="radio" name="Artwork" id="ifEmail" value="Email"   style="margin-bottom: 10px">Email </label>
    <label class="radio-inline"> <input type="radio"  id="ifOther" name ="Artwork" value="Other" style="margin-bottom: 10px">Other</label>
  </div>
  <div id="div_ifOther" class="controls col-md-8 " style="display:none;">
    <input class="input-md  textinput textInput form-control" maxlength="30" name="Artwork" placeholder="Other" style="margin-bottom: 10px" type="text" />
  </div>
```

Comment: What is the value of `Artwork` when submitting the form ?. Can you do a `var_dump('$_REQUEST');`.

Comment: get value null sir

Comment: You will have to put your php script so that we can debug it.

Comment: done edit, i show my php script. please help sir..

Comment: Using `.click(fn)` on forms is not good idea. User can change value or radio using keyboard.

Comment: You use the same `name` for the radios **and** the input. Use a different `name` for the latter... something like `artworkText`.

Comment: Regarding @jiwopene's comment... You should use a `change` handler. I would suggest `$("input[name='Artwork']").on('change',function(){`.

Answer (score 1):

Change input's `name` attribute and it should work.

As the radio buttons and the input `name` attribute is `Artwork`. the form is taking the last one, thus only the input's value is sent.

```
<div id="div_id_select" class="form-group required">
  <label for="id_Artwork"  class="control-label col-md-4  requiredField"> Artwork :<span class="asteriskField">*</span> </label>
  <div class="controls col-md-9 "  style="margin-bottom: 10px">
    <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" checked="checked" name="Artwork" id="ifUsb"  value="Usb"  style="margin-bottom: 10px">Usb</label>
    <label class="radio-inline"> <input type="radio" name="Artwork" id="ifEmail" value="Email"   style="margin-bottom: 10px">Email </label>
    <label class="radio-inline"> <input type="radio"  id="ifOther" name ="Artwork" value="Other" style="margin-bottom: 10px">Other</label>
  </div>
  <div id="div_ifOther" class="controls col-md-8 " style="display:none;">
    <input class="input-md  textinput textInput form-control" maxlength="30" name="artwork_text" placeholder="Other" style="margin-bottom: 10px" type="text" />
  </div>
```